# DB2 - Select values based on number of days in current month

Tags: db2

I have table something like below.

TABLE NAME (issues):

```
ID  ISSUE_ID  CREATED_DATE 
1   101       15 July 2016 
2   102       13 July 2016 
3   103       10 July 2016 
4   104       8 July 2016  
5   103       7 July 2016  
6   104       19 June 2016 
7   103       10 June 2016 
8   104       1 June 2016
```

I want retrieve number of issues(count) that was opened in last 30/31/28 days based on number of days in current month.

For example, 
In the month of July, we have 31 days, so I want to retrieve issues that got opened in last 31 days.

If in case of June, we have only 30 days, so I have to retrieve issues that was opened in last 30 days.

In DB2, number of days on this month can be retrieved by

```
DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE(current timestamp)))
```

I am still confused how to apply it to a query. 
I have a very limited knowledge on queries.

Thanks in advance.

The following query didn't work.

```
SELECT 
  count(*)
  FROM issues
WHERE
  MONTH(CREATED_DATE) > (MONTH( DATE(current timestamp) ) - 1 MONTH)
  AND 
  DAY(DATE (CREATED_DATE)) > DAY(DATE(current timestamp))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can substitute in value for the number of days.

basic back in time select

```
select * from sometable where somedate > current date - 31 days
```

back in time select using a function for the number of days.

```
select * from sometable where somedate > current date -

DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE(current timestamp))) days
```

But most of us select back a month with a month

```
select * from sometable where somedate > current date - 1 months
```

Note: The only place where I've found the back N days useful is pulling out stuff from the weekend on Monday or Holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
  count(*)
  FROM issues
WHERE CREATED_DATE>DAY(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE))
```

If CREATED_DATE is not date format. try this

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM issues
WHERE TO_DATE('CREATED_DATE', 'DD MONTH YYYY')>DAY(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE))
```